# Can a Raspberry Pi Zero be used as a Wi-FI Access Point?

Tags: raspbian, networking, hardware, wireless-adapter, pi-zero

I just recently bought the Raspberry Pi Zero and a wireless usb adapter w/ antennas (http://amzn.to/1UH8Hd7) and I wanted to know if it could be used as a router. I know that there is no ethernet port, but usually routers made out of Raspberry Pi's only need the usb antenna. Is it possible to use that adapter w/ my RPi Zero to turn it into a router?

(What im doing with the RPiZero is based off this tutorial: http://jacobsalmela.com/raspberry-pi-and-routing-turning-a-pi-into-a-router/)

Comment: The first problem would be adding USB-ports to the Pi Zero, you might find something by searching for "pi zero usb hack" or trying [this](http://hackaday.com/2015/12/03/4-port-usb-raspberry-pi-zero-piggy-back-hack/). I cannot say if the link works, another user should look over that. The second problem will be setting up hostapd, you need a wifi-adapter that can be used by hostapd. If the usb-adapter is not on the positive-list (e.g. [this here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)), you might experience problems.

Comment: the tutorial i am using states the adapter as working with hostapd, so i think that wont be a worry. as for the usb port thing, im thinking about getting a usb otg host cable (potentially a dual one). Do you think that would work?

Comment: @Thomas Shera
And how do you do that? I have searched high and low and cannot find a method that works with my piZero. If you know how to do this, please reply with more detailed instructions. I simply need to connect to my Zero via wifi so I can ssh without depending on wifi since I'll be taking it to various places and I won't have the time or tools to set up wifi connectivity for each different SSID. Any and all advice welcome

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use USB to Ethernet adapter for about 20 bucks (at this point would raspberry pi 2 be better value per dollar?) Or solder Ethernet like how you can solder USB. or write a Linux script which uses incoming WiFi disk to create hotspot, like how mobile phone does, except for progress it's using data, not WiFi.

Comment: And how do you do that? I have searched high and low and cannot find a method that works with my piZero. If you know how to do this, please reply with more detailed instructions. I simply need to connect to my Zero via wifi so I can ssh without depending on wifi since I'll be taking it to various places and I won't have the time or tools to set up wifi connectivity for each different SSID. Any and all advice welcome

Comment: this might be a good separate question, someone might see it now.

Answer (score 0):

We gonna have the follow elements:

1. You need to know that RPI Zero only have 1 usb adapter, at this point you need a simply setup, internet IN, internet OUT. To make it work, needs a RPI Zero W (Wireless). Etheret usb adapter as IN and integrated wireless on RPI as OUT.
2. The easy way to have a wireless router is with DHCP on your wireless setup.
3. Simulation: INTERNET comes to your ethernet adapter from your ISP (home, office router, with ethernet patchcord), and this share the connection to your integrated wireless on RPI, the interface 1 masquerade on interface 2 (Producing a NAT).

Now here the steps on setup by my self, I hope it works for you!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8oenbX7S5knbWFyc1pHLUJTbk0

Good Luck!